# How to do alphanum sorting in javascripts

Tags: javascript

Here is my JavaScript code to sort data in an alphanumeric way:

```
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
function sortAlphaNum(a,b) {
    var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
    var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
    if(aA === bA) {
        var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

my input data:

```
["ap1", "ap4", "ap12","4ggh2","7ggh9","9tggfg2","4gghdd2","4gghfg2"]
```

after sorting it should be like :

```
4ggh2,4hghdd2,4kghfg2,7ggh9,9tggfg2,ap1,ap4,ap12
```

which is not happening could you please help me out in this.

```
function sortAlphaNum(a, b) { 
    var x = a.split("/"); 
    var y = b.split("/"); 
    x = x[x.length-1].replace(/\\\s/g," ").split(/(\d )/); 
    y = y[y.length-1].replace(/\\\s/g," ").split(/(\d )/);  
    for (var i in x) { 
        if (x[i] && !y[i] || isFinite(x[i]) && !isFinite(y[i])) { 
            return -1; 
        } else if (!x[i] && y[i] || !isFinite(y[i]) && isFinite(y[i])) { 
            return 1; 
        } else if (!isFinite(x[i]) && !isFinite(y[i])) { 
            x[i] = x[i].toLowerCase(); 
            y[i] = y[i].toLowerCase(); 
            if (x[i] < y[i]) return -1; 
            if (x[i] > y[i]) return 1; 
        } else { 
            x[i] = parseFloat(x[i]); 
            y[i] = parseFloat(y[i]); 
            if (x[i] < y[i]) return -1; 
            if (x[i] > y[i]) return 1; 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
alert(["ap1", "ap4", "ap12","4ggh2","7ggh9","9tggfg2","4hghdd2","4kghfg2"].sort(sortAlphaNum));
```

Comment: var input = ["ap1", "ap4", "ap12","4ggh2","7ggh9","9tggfg2","4gghdd2","4gghfg2"]

Comment: out put should be like : 4ggh2,4hghdd2,4kghfg2,7ggh9,9tggfg2,ap1,ap4,ap12

Comment: You didn't show how you sort your data. By the way, `input = input.sort()` should be sufficient. What's somehow very strange: Your example output has different entries than your input.

Comment: @Zeta - The `sort` function modifies the original array. Just `input.sort()` would suffice.

Comment: So you've just copied code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array ?

Comment: The code you have now only works for a more limited pattern (leading letters, then a single number).

Answer (score 1):

This example adds a method to the Array prototype,

but it can be written as a standalone function with the array to be sorted passed as an argument if you prefer.

```
Array.prototype.naturalSort= function(index){
    var T= this, L= T.length, i, who, next, 
    isi= typeof index== 'number', 
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    function nSort(aa, bb){
        var a= aa[0], b= bb[0], a1, b1, i= 0, n, L= a.length;
        while(i<L){
            if(!b[i]) return 1;
            a1= a[i];
            b1= b[i++];
            if(a1!== b1){
                n= a1-b1;
                if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
                return a1>b1? 1:-1;
            }
        }
        return b[i]? -1:0;
    }
    for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
        who= T[i];
        next= isi? T[i][index] || '':who;
        T[i]= [String(next).toLowerCase().match(rx), who];
    }
    T.sort(nSort);
    for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
        T[i]= T[i][1];
    }
    return this;
}
var A= ["ap1","ap4","ap12","4ggh2","7ggh9","9tggfg2","4gghdd2","4gghfg2"];

A.naturalSort();
```

// returned value: (Array)
   // **4ggh2,4gghdd2,4gghfg2,7ggh9,9tggfg2,ap1,ap4,ap12**

> 1. The example first goes through the entire array and sets each item to a new two-item array- the first item of the new array is a matched
>      array of numbers and strings,  the second is the original value.
>
> In your example, array[5]= '9tggfg2', becomes array[5]= [['9',
>   'tggfg', '2'], '9tggfg2']]. That way the reg exp, match and and
>   toLowerCase operations are only done once for each item,  rather than
>   every time the sort compares two items.
>
> 1. After the array is prepped, the sort function is applied, which compares items alphabetically if they are both alpha-strings and
>      numerically if they are both number-strings. Number-strings sort
>      before(are less-than) alpha-strings.
> 2. After the sort, the array is again processed, this time to reset each item to its original value.

You can use the same logic without the pre-sort and post-sort parts, 
but if you have more than three items it takes longer:

```
function natSort(as, bs){
    var a, b, a1, b1, i= 0, n, L, 
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    a= String(as).toLowerCase().match(rx);
    b= String(bs).toLowerCase().match(rx);
    if(as=== bs) return 0;
    L= a.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(!b[i]) return 1;
        a1= a[i], 
        b1= b[i++];
        if(a1!== b1){
            n= a1-b1;
            if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
            return a1>b1? 1:-1;
        }
    }
    return b[i]? -1:0;
}
   ["ap1", "ap4", "ap12", "4ggh2", "7ggh9", 
"9tggfg2", "4gghdd2", "4gghfg2"].sort(natSort);
```

returned value: (Array)
    **4ggh2,4gghdd2,4gghfg2,7ggh9,9tggfg2,ap1,ap4,ap12**

Comment: I have like 350 item in the coloum so wheather it would work fine or not i have not tried yet with more data

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var input = ["ap1", "ap4", "ap12","4ggh2","7ggh9","9tggfg2","4gghdd2","4gghfg2"];
input.sort();
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xmkVr/

Comment: The result does not match the one expected by author(check last three terms).

Comment: That does not sort `ap4` between `ap1` and `ap12`.

Comment: plz see the above code where i am using sort function as well but its sorting like this 4ggh2,4hghdd2,4kghfg2,7ggh9,9tggfg2,ap1,ap12,ap4

Comment: but i need to use the function inside sort function