# Sort array of addresses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array of addresses. Seems simple enough by using the `.sort()` method on my array.

But...
Try looking here: https://jsfiddle.net/ytuzr918/

The `.sort()` method sorts perfectly alphabetically (at least I assume it does). However my addresses have numbers and even more letters after the numbers.

So is there a way to sort the array "right", probably by prototyping the sort method?

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a comparison function to `Array.prototype.sort()`.

Adapting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array) :

```
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
function sortAlphaNum(a,b) {
    var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
    var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
    if(aA === bA) {
        var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
console.log(addresses.sort(sortAlphanum));
```

Answer (score 2):

Array sort method in javascript takes one optional argument which is a compare function. You can define this compare function as per your requirements.

> arr.sort([compareFunction])
>
> **compareFunction(Optional)**. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each
>   character's Unicode code point value, according to the string
>   conversion of each element.

See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common sorting for the `.sort()` function. What you could do is pass the method your own custom comparison function so that it'll use that to determine sort order.

```
addresses.sort(function (a, b) {
  var val_a = Number.parseInt(a.replace('Nordmarksvej ', ''));
  var val_b = Number.parseInt(b.replace('Nordmarksvej ', ''));

  if (val_a === val_b) {
    return 0;
  }

  return val_a > val_b ? 1 : -1
});
```