# How to sort an array comprised of alpha-numeric strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I have the following array:

```
var num = [10% cats, 20% dogs, 30% fish, 40% turtles];
```

where a pct value is always concatenated to a label. Is there an easy way to ort from largest percentage to smallest? Unlike other similar questions, the format here is always `xx% label`

using `.sort()` in the usual `.sort(function(a,b) {return b-a;}):` doesn't work since these are not numerals?

output should be:

```
num = [40% turtles, 30% fish, 20% dogs, 10% cats];
```

Comment: are you certain that the first two characters would always be numbers ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort mixed alpha/numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array)

Comment: `.sort((a,b) => Number(b.split('%')[0]) - Number(a.split('%')[0]))` - that assumes that `var num` is fixed to be a valid array of strings `['10% cats', '20% dogs', '30% fish', '40% turtles']`

Comment: or more simply `.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a))`

Comment: Yest, the 1st two characters are derived from user inputs (type=numbers) - so always starts with numerals (either 1 or 2 digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sort function that converts the strings into numerical values before comparing them to sort by percentages.

```js
var num = ['10% cats', '20% dogs', '30% fish', '40% turtles'];

num.sort( sortByPercentage );

console.log( num );

function sortByPercentage( a,b ) {
  a = parseFloat(a);
  b = parseFloat(b);
  return b-a;
}
```

Comment: `if you know you will have integer percentages` - you could always use `parseFloat` instead

Comment: Dang! forgot that parseFloat would strip everything but the numerals! Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localeCompare` for sorting specifying the `numeric` option.

```js
var num = ['10% cats', '20% dogs', '40% turtles', '30% fish'];
num.sort((a,b) => b.localeCompare(a, undefined, {numeric:true})); 
console.log(num);
```