# Lodash sorting of mixed string and number (address)

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
let records = [
    {name: 'damilola', address: 'house 11'},
    {name: 'adeniji', address: 'House 1'},
    {name: 'segun', address: 'House 2'},
    {name: 'nathan', address: 'House 3'},
    {name: 'damilola', address: 'house 12'},
    {name: 'damilola', address: 'house12me'},
    {name: 'damilola', address: 'house11me'},
];

return _.orderBy(records, "address", "asc");
```

i want to sort this with lodash method only

Desired Output:

```
[{name: 'adeniji', address: 'House 1'},
{name: 'segun', address: 'House 2'},
{name: 'nathan', address: 'House 3'},
{name: 'damilola', address: 'house 11'}
{name: 'damilola', address: 'house 12'}
{name: 'damilola', address: 'house11me'}
{name: 'damilola', address: 'house12me'}]
```

Comment: Sort it _how_? By what criteria and in which direction?

Comment: Please update the question with desired output and the logic behind it. Currently, your question is unclear.

Comment: return _.orderBy(records, "adress", "asc");

Comment: _.orderBy(records, ['adress'], ['asc']); try this

Comment: You can use custom callback, split that address string and compare its parts

Comment: how to do it? @barbsan

Comment: @HassanImam i have corrected the question, it is something related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array but in lodash way

Comment: @Phil, i have corrected the question, hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`string#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). To numerically sort the array use `numeric` property.

```js
let records = [ {name: 'damilola', address: 'house 11'}, {name: 'adeniji', address: 'House 1'}, {name: 'segun', address: 'House 2'}, {name: 'nathan', address: 'House 3'}, {name: 'damilola', address: 'house 12'}, {name: 'damilola', address: 'house12me'},{name: 'damilola', address: 'house11me'}];
records.sort((a,b) => a.address.localeCompare(b.address, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(records);
```

Comment: this is close to the solution  but i want know how _lodash implementation can solve it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
const sorted = _.orderBy(records, ["name", "address"])
```

Also, here's lodash documentation for this method: https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy

Comment: i am not sorting multiple keys/fields, something like_.orderBy(records, "address"); but when doing that it does not sort it very welll, i am having issue of  proper ordering

Comment: So you're only sorting by address. Could you provide the expected output? What the sorted array would look like?

Comment: something like this

Comment: I have corrected the question, something related to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array but in lodash way