# How to sort an array of objects with alphabets first and then with numbers in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code:

```
keyword.sort((a, b) => a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr));
```

Current output:

```
[{
        "Id": 947,
        "Acr": 502,
        "Definition": "ADefBulk6",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "Id": 762,
        "Acr": "AO",
        "Definition": "Anti",
        "ID": 762,
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "Id": 72,
        "Acr": "AW",
        "Definition": "Corporate",
        "ID": 762,
        "index": 1
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
        "Id": 947,
        "Acr": "AO",
        "Definition": "ADefBulk6",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "Id": 762,
        "Acr": "AW",
        "Definition": "Anti",
        "ID": 762,
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "Id": 72,
        "Acr": 502,
        "Definition": "Corporate",
        "ID": 762,
        "index": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: See this please: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array/62766690#62766690](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array/62766690#62766690)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort mixed alpha/numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the types if both strings, sort them. If both numbers sort them. If different, move string before.

```js
var arr = [{
        "Acr": 502,
    }, {
        "Acr": "AO",
    }, {
        "Acr": "AW",
    }, {
        "Acr": 402,
    }
];
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  var tA = typeof a.Acr;
  var tB = typeof b.Acr;
  if (tA === tB && tA === "string") {
    return a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr);
  } else if (tA === tB && tA === "number") {
    return a.Acr - b.Acr;
  } else {
    return tA === "string" ? -1 : 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

If they are all stored as strings

```js
var arr = [{
        "Acr": "502",
    }, {
        "Acr": "AO",
    }, {
        "Acr": "AW",
    }, {
        "Acr": "402",
    }
];
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  var tA = a.Acr.match(/^\d+$/) ? 'number' : 'string';
  var tB = b.Acr.match(/^\d+$/) ? 'number' : 'string';
  if (tA === tB && tA === "string") {
    return a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr);
  } else if (tA === tB && tA === "number") {
    return +a.Acr - +b.Acr;
  } else {
    return tA === "string" ? -1 : 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if my array is something like this? var arr = [{
        "Acr": "502",
    }, {
        "Acr": "AO",
    }, {
        "Acr": "AW",
    }, {
        "Acr": "402",
    }, {
        "Acr": "401(c)(d)"
];
I just want the Acr string values that start with a digit to appear after the alphabet string values. Could you help?

Comment: @TiaSengupta: Check my updated answer for `Acr`-values with number-strings.

Comment: I think with this solution `"401(c)(d)"` will not be sorted behind the alpha-chars ...

Comment: What would be the suitable approach for that?

Comment: @eol I do not see that in the OPs values. Seems like it was either numbers or letters. If it is mixed, using the one dupe link (which has my solution) would work.

Comment: It's mentioned in the first comment under this answer..

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the sort callback if both `Acr`-values are strings, if yes return the result of the string-comparison. If only one of the values is a string give it priority and if neither of them is a string (I'm assuming you only have numbers and strings as their values), return the (signed) difference of the values. Something like this should do it:

```
const arr=[
{"Id":949,"Acr":900,"Definition":"ADefBulk6","index":0},
{"Id":947,"Acr":502,"Definition":"ADefBulk6","index":0},
{"Id":762,"Acr":"AW","Definition":"Anti","ID":762,"index":1},
{"Id":72,"Acr":"AO","Definition":"Corporate","ID":762,"index":1},
{"Id":76,"Acr":"AA","Definition":"Corporate","ID":762,"index":1}];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a.Acr === 'string' && typeof b.Acr === 'string') {
        return a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr);
    } else if (typeof a.Acr === 'string') {
        return -1;
    } else if (typeof b.Acr === 'string') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Math.sign(a.Acr - b.Acr);
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

For values with number-strings, you can do:

```js
const arr = [
    {"Id": 949, "Acr": "900", "Definition": "ADefBulk6", "index": 0},
    {"Id": 947, "Acr": "502", "Definition": "ADefBulk6", "index": 0},
    {"Id": 762, "Acr": "AW", "Definition": "Anti", "ID": 762, "index": 1},
    {"Id": 72, "Acr": "AO", "Definition": "Corporate", "ID": 762, "index": 1},    
    {"Id":73,  "Acr": "401(c)(d)","Definition":"Corporate","ID":762,"index":1},
    {"Id": 76, "Acr": "AA", "Definition": "Corporate", "ID": 762, "index": 1}];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const nrA = Number.parseInt(a.Acr);
    const nrB = Number.parseInt(b.Acr);

    if (isNaN(nrA) && isNaN(nrB)) {
        return a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr);
    } else if (isNaN(nrA)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (isNaN(nrB)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Math.sign(nrA - nrB);
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it to sort them separately and then add them together

```js
sortx=[{ "Id": 947, "Acr": 502, "Definition": "ADefBulk6", "index": 0 },  { "Id": 72, "Acr": "AW", "Definition": "Corporate", "ID": 762, "index": 1 },{ "Id": 762, "Acr": "AO", "Definition": "Anti", "ID": 762, "index": 1 }, { "Id": 100, "Acr": 100, "Definition": "Anti", "ID": 762, "index": 1 } ]
var sortalph=sortx.filter(o=>typeof(o.Acr)=="string").sort((a,b)=>a.Acr.localeCompare(b.Acr))
var sortnum=sortx.filter(o=>typeof(o.Acr)=="number").sort((a,b)=>a.Acr-b.Acr)

console.log([...sortalph,...sortnum])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response