# Transfer Google doc files in google drive to another domain

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-drive-shared-drive

Ownership is not transferable from @google.com to another domain.

anyway to migrate the 15GB free drive account to a workspace business account?
(must include the google doc files)

- trial

  - Even if the 15gb account is granted content manager, folder in 15gb account still cannot move to shared drive of the workspace account
    [image]

    - reason [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7374057?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmove-drive-folders-to-shared-drives-as-an-admin)   "" You can only move folders owned by a user in your organization.""

Answer (score -1):

I'd do the following:

1. Make a shared drive on your Workspace account.
2. Give `Content manager` permissions to your free account.
3. Copy or move the files to the drive.
4. Move the files to your new account root folder.
5. (optional) Remove the shared drive, or revoke your free account's permissions to it.

Alternatively, since you have a Workspace account, you can [contact Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).

Comment: step 4  requires downloading all files to local and reupload right?

Comment: also how to transfer the shared drive to the original drive of workspace?

Comment: You can move files and folders within the web client (right click). No need to download it. Also, you wouldn't transfer the shared drive, you share it. Basically is a drive that both have access to.

Comment: I mean I don't want the files to be in a shared drive of the workspace account, eventually, I want it to be in the "My Drive" of the workspace account, do I just simply drag them to the "My Drive"

Comment: @LukAron Oh, this seems to happens when you move from the gmail account to the workspace shared drive (but works fine when moving from the shared drive to its root folder). You may use Apps Script to automatically copy all the folders recursively to the shared drive ([see code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66473822/14779804)). You could also make a similar script for any Drive API client.

Comment: thanks ,seems apps scripts couldn't authenticate both accounts, I must copy from to "MyDrive" to  shared drive first, and then I move to "MyDrive" of the workspace account.