# Angular Object Array Sorting

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

Trying to sort the array of object, the property of the object contains alphanumeric values,
Tried methods which didn't worked

test.sort((a,b)=> a.Code.localeCompare(b.Code));
test.sort((a,b)=> +a.Code- +b.Code);

```js
let test = [{Code: '16', Color: "Red"},
      {Code: '54', Color: "Yellow"},
      {Code: '24', Color: "Yellow"},
      {Code: '1600', Color: "Blue"},
      {Code: '16a', Color: "Green"},
      {Code: '22', Color: "Yellow"},
      {Code: '23', Color: "Yellow"}];

 test.sort((a,b) =>  a.Code.localeCompare(b.Code));
 console.log(test);
```

getting output as

```
[{"Code": "16", "Color": "Red" },
{"Code": "1600","Color": "Blue"},
{"Code": "16a","Color": "Green"},
{"Code": "22","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "23","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "24","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "54","Color": "Yellow"}]
```

How I can get the Expected output as

```
[{"Code": "16", "Color": "Red" },    
{"Code": "22","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "23","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "24","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "54","Color": "Yellow"},
{"Code": "1600","Color": "Blue"},
{"Code": "16a","Color": "Green"}]
```

Comment: where you copied this `a.Code.localeCompare(b.Code));` may they also said how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for numbers and move number to top and sort by numbers or by string.

```js
let test = [{ Code: '16', Color: "Red" }, { Code: '54', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '24', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '1600', Color: "Blue" }, { Code: '16a', Color: "Green" }, { Code: '22', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '23', Color: "Yellow" }];

test.sort(({ Code: a }, { Code: b }) =>
    isFinite(b) - isFinite(a) ||
    a - b ||
    a.localeCompare(b)
);
console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something as follows;

`test.sort(a,b) =>  a.Code.localeCompare(b.Code, 'en', { numeric: true }`);

There is other possible solution if the above does not work as you expect.

Ref: [Sort mixed alpha/numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) a slight modification done to the solution as typescript was restricting typecasting

```js
let test = [{ Code: '16', Color: "Red" }, { Code: '54', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '24', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '1600', Color: "Blue" }, { Code: '16a', Color: "Green" }, { Code: '22', Color: "Yellow" }, { Code: '23', Color: "Yellow" }];

test.sort(({ Code: a }, { Code: b }) =>
    +isFinite(+b) - +isFinite(+a) ||
    +a - +b ||
    a.localeCompare(b)
); 

console.log(test);
```