# Sort array of objects by alphanumeric string property value

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, object

I want to sort an array of objects in TypeScript which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Picture3.jpg",
        "targetRange": "B2",
        "type": "Bitmap"
    },
     {
        "title": "Picture2.jpg",
        "targetRange": "A2",
        "type": "Bitmap"
    },
    {
        "title": "Picture1.jpg",
        "targetRange": "A1",
        "type": "Bitmap"
    }
]
```

I want to have my objects sorted after the targetRange in following order: A1, A2, B2

I refered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value), but it won't sort it in any way.

How can I sort them by the value of targetRange in TypeScript?

I tried the following things already:

```
this.objs.sort((a, b) => a.targetRange!.localeCompare(b.targetRange!));
```

and

````
 this.objs.sort((a,b) => (a.targetRange! < b.targetRange!) ? 1 : ((b.targetRange! > a.targetRange!) ? -1 : 0))```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort mixed alpha/numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine [on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BcBvARFAllANvNS0ATpmAOYA0UAhkWfFAErXnyFQnlUCeADm8VJkAvgG0AujAC8MUQFgAUDGUwUilRpgZseAloAKmYFACuReAGYAdACteZNBXWblGWvSYt6etACEATI7OLhh8+EhavtgAttS8aMEwwk5KGmqpIVi44QZGpub+tvZBGZpudAzMrD4AgoEpLq5QYT5RULHxicmJ6Y1aWboRaIbGZvAAjEUODY3lHlXeQzXjJX2h-K0xcQmlworiiqCQsAAe0nCIUFYQIERQABT31BQwAEYAlNIAfDDUVjQVTysKw4EDAah4ADCIGivFo8Hur3+7kqXng73eAG5DuAbngQSAyPcTu8gA)

The Problem has to be somewhere else