# Sort select box classic asp

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a select box which is loaded from the database. I can't change nothing in the database, so i need to sort (from A to Z) the select box in the client side. I can use ither vbscript or javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a previously answered Stack Overflow question that sorts a select box using Javascript: [Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element/278509#278509)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the recordset on the page after you get the data from the database.

Try using...

rs.Sort="FieldName"

and the data will be resorted.