# How to add a option to a select box in the correct position dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the select box below. I want to be able to dynamically add a new option.

```
<select id="user_department_id" name="user[department_id]">

 <option value=""> </option>

 <option value="9">AAAAA</option>
 <option value="11">BBBBB</option>
 <option value="10">G</option>
 <option value="12">Z</option>

 <option value="">--</option>
 <option value="add">Add a New</option>
</select>
```

I have been using the following to add a new option:

```
$('#user_department_id')
    .prepend($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value",data.id)
    .text(data.title)
);
```

The problem here is that it is position unnaturally, it's above the empty placeholder option and not sorted alphabetically. Is there a magic way to append a new select option in the correct place?

Thanks

Comment: The code you provided changes the selection, it does not add an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the code with the sample that adds an option.

Comment: SKS, the problem by sorting is that it won't maintain the -- and the Add option at the bottom correct?

Comment: @AnApprentice Remove those 2 options, Sort it and Add them back.

Answer (score 3):

This inserts a new option value into  (assuming it is already sorted)

```
$('#yourselectID option').each(function()
{
  var option = $(this).text();
  option = option.toLowerCase(); 
  var test = option.toLowerCase();
  if ( option > test) 
{
    $(this).before('<option value="'+test+'">' + test+ '</option>');
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Beware of this snippet: the option won't be inserted if it should be inserted as last element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use .after('blah') with the selector you described.

for example:

```
$('#user_department_id option[value="12"]').after('<option value="13">Q</option>')
```

is that of any use?

Comment: Oh, after reading I see the problem is more about sorting? Please disregard.

Comment: If the sort is based on the option text, just treat it as an insertion sort, iterating over the options and checking the text of each option; then, use .after(...) as @Nick mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you can remove the option that you don't want to sort and then add them back.

**Note:** The below will work in your case because you want the `--` and `Add New` at the end.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/T6bCL/2/)

```
    var selElem = document.getElementById('user_department_id')
    var tmpAry = [];
    var igOpt = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selElem.options.length; i++) {

        if ($(selElem.options[i]).hasClass('ig')) {
            igOpt.push([selElem.options[i].text,
                        selElem.options[i].value]);
            continue;
        }
        tmpAry[i] = new Array();
        tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
        tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
    }
    tmpAry.sort();
    //merge with ignored options
    tmpAry = tmpAry.concat(igOpt);
    //remove options
    $(selElem).empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < tmpAry.length; i++) {
        var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
        selElem.options[i] = op;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that has Add New now in the middle of the list

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but this should do:

```
$('#user_department_id option').each(function() {
  if(this.text > data.title) {
    $(this).before('<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.title + '</option>');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your options in an array of objects and generate your select from that object.  Then add your new items to that array and regenerate your select.

```
$(function() {
    // Any options always on the top
    var topOptions = '<option value=""> </option>';

    // Your middle, sorted options
    var options = [{val: 9, text: "AAAAA"}, {val: 11, text: "BBBBB"},{val: 10, text: "G"},{val: 12, text: "Z"}];

    // Any options always on the bottom
    var bottomOptions = '<option value="">--</option><option value="add">Add a New</option>';

    // Function to populate the select options from above data
    function populateOptions(element, options) {
        // Sort options
        options = options.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase();
        });

        $(element).html('').append(topOptions);
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            $('<option>').attr("value", options[i].val).text(options[i].text).appendTo($(element));
        }
        $(element).append(bottomOptions);
    }

    // Start by populating the select
    populateOptions('#user_department_id', options);

    // Add and repopulate when add requested
    $('#user_department_id').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "add") {
            // Add option to list
            options.push({val: data.id, text: data.text});

            // Repopulate select
            populateOptions(this, options);

            // Select the new item
            $(this).val(data.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kfC3S/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [underscore's `sortedIndex`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortedIndex) to figure out where to insert the item and then [jquery's `after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function to insert it at that position.  This is assuming you want to sort by option text alphabetically:

```
var option = '<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.title + '</option>';
var index = _.sortedIndex($('#user_department_id option'), option, function(item) {
  return $(item).text();
});
if(index === 0) {
  $('#user_department_id').prepend(option);
} else {
  $('#user_department_id option').eq(index - 1).after(option);
}
```