# jQuery Appending item to Select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a select list and if the item the user needs isn't listed, they can add it via another input box and then the item will be appended to the select list.

```
$("#misc_userID").effect("transfer", { to: $("#group_misc_available") }, 500);
```

Now, my problem is if the user enters a multiple word item (e.g. 'John from HP'), the spaces in the phrase don't transfer correctly (see below via FireBug):

```
<option hp="" from="" value="John">John from HP</option>
```

I'm using the following jQuery code to append the item from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712660/jquery-move-item-from-one-select-box-to-another-while-retaining-listing-order):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('select').append($this.find('option:selected')); // append selected option to sibling
        $('select', this.parent()).each(function(i,v){ // loop through relative selects
            var $options = $(v).find('option'); // get all options
            $options = $options.sort(function(a,b){ // sort by value of options
                return a.value - b.value;
            });
        (this).html($options); // add new sorted options to select
        });
    });   
});
```

it is almost like I need to encode it before the transfer and then a decode afterwards.

I coudln't get the jsfiddle to work so here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="misc_userID" id="misc_userID" value="" size="30" max="100" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" name="misc_AddUpdate_btn" id="misc_AddUpdate_btn" value="Save Contributor" />
</p>
<p>
    <select name="group_misc_available" size="10" multiple="multiple" id="group_misc_available" class="group_misc_selects_control" style="width:140px;">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <img src="../Common/MultiSelect/img/switch.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <select name="group_misc_selected" size="10" multiple="multiple" id="group_misc_selected" class="group_misc_selects_control"  style="width:140px;">
    </select>
</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('select').append($this.find('option:selected')); // append selected option to sibling
        $('select', $this.parent()).each(function(i,v){                 // loop through relative selects
            var $options = $(v).find('option');                         // get all options
            $options = $options.sort(function(a,b){                     // sort by value of options
                return a.value - b.value;
            });
            $(this).html($options);                                     // add new sorted options to select
        });
    });   
    $('#misc_AddUpdate_btn').click(function(){
            var contributor = $('#misc_userID').val();
            if ( (contributor==null) || (contributor=="") ){
                //    do nothing
                alert('You must enter the Miscellaneous Contributor first.');
            }
            else {
                //    console.log('button pressed');
                var path_to_save_contributor = '/vtil/ajax/GroupContributor_Misc_lookup.cfm';
                var data_to_send = 'misc_userID='+contributor;

                $("#misc_userID").effect("transfer", { to: $("#group_misc_available") }, 500);
                setTimeout(function() {AddElement(contributor);}, 500);
            }
        });

        function AddElement(contributor){
                    $('#misc_userID').val('');    // reset value back to null    
                    var UpdateItem=decodeURIComponent(contributor);
                    $("#group_misc_available").append('<option value=' + UpdateItem + '>' + UpdateItem + '</option>');
                }
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.parent()`? you cannot use jQuery's `parent()` method for Raw DOM objects. Do you mean `$this.parent()`?

Comment: Encoding is probably a good idea.  Have you tried that?  What where the results of it?

Comment: I used encodeURIComponent to encode it.  Using the text from the question, `John from HP` became `John%20from%20HP` but I don't know how to decode it.  :blush:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpicks:

- `this.parent()` should be `$this.parent()`.
- `(this).html($options);` should be `$this.html($options);` (or maybe `$(this).html($options);`?).

Those aside, `John%20from%20HP` can be converted to `John from HP` using `unescape()`, though I recommend using `decodeURIComponent()` in this case, instead. (Since you used `encodeURIComponent()` initially.)

Since you can't encode/decode something recovered by `find()` (since it's a jQuery object, not a string), you can reorganize your code like so:

```
$this.find('option:selected')
     .html(decodeURIComponent($this.find('option:selected').html()))
     .appendTo($this.siblings('select'));
```

You can see the code in action [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHfxd/) (ignored the sorting code here).

If this code still isn't exactly working, we'd need to see an example in action.

Comment: the nitpicks just didn't come through when I pasted the code.  Your code looked good but unfortunately the sorting is a requirement for this project.  I added a the code above  - I couldn't get it to work right in the jsfiddle.

Comment: You can add the sorting yourself. I just removed it for simplicity of the fiddle. Does the code I provided not work when you add the sorting?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now.  Let me try.

Comment: I've put your code in a fiddle and it's just... a bit mixed up. The sorting code is not even called until you click an option. But when I add a name, it doesn't give me a `%20`. [Clicky for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6J8dy/1/).

Comment: Thanks for putting it so um, delicately. LOL  :)  and thanks for getting the fiddle to work.  Using your fiddle, I added 'Hello World' and then used FireBug to see what was saved as the option and it was `<option world="" value="Hello">Hello World</option>`.  Now /THAT/ is messed up.  :)  The select boxes are working orshould I say the client is happy with that part.  I'm trying to make it where they can dynamically add new items without a page refresh since there are a LOT of other elements on this page.

Comment: Also, I've removed the ajax stuff that saves the value entered into the input text box.  That might be the missing gap you are referring too.

Comment: If AJAX is just saving the value, it shouldn't be adding `%20`. And yes, I see that weird `world=""` part, and that's in your `AddElement` method. So what part of this is still not working properly for you?

Comment: The option should be `<option value="Hello World">Hello World</option/>` when hello World was entered into the input field with id of misc_userID but it isn't.  The second part of the entry "world" is being added as its own attribute.

Comment: Ah, okay. Take a look at my changes to `AddElement` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6J8dy/2/). Basically, I made the `<option>` tag as a jQuery object and added the `value` attribute through `.attr()`.

Comment: OMG, you did it!  I can't believe you hung with me this long!  Thank you!  I'll mark this as the answer now.

Comment: Note to anyone else, your select box should NOT have `multiple="multiple"` or else if the user selects several at a time, the values selected all become the same.  Removing the `'multiple="multiple"'`  removes that from happening.