# Ordering a `<select>` with JavaScript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a `<select>` element which has some initial values, how can I add a value to the select and then order it alphabetically.

I can add options with some simple JavaScript:

```
var select = document.getElementById("example-select");
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
```

...but that only appends it to the end.

**How can I sort a `<select>` element by JavaScript without using jQuery.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to sort contents of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element)

Comment: Are the current options sorted?

Comment: @user1689607 Yes, It's just the added item that doesn't follow the alphabetical order.

Comment: do you want to order by option value or option text? Are the inital values of the select already ordered so you just need to insert the new one ordered?

Comment: Is it ordered by the text or by the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try.

```
var select = document.getElementById("example-select");

var options = select.options;
var newOption = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');

for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (newOption.text.localeCompare(options[i].text) < 0) {
        break;
    }
}

select.insertBefore(newOption, options[i] || null);
```

Comment: @LazyTarget: Thanks. I had a mistake that I just corrected. Nice thing is that it doesn't require the expensive sort, but presumes a current alphabetical order.

Comment: I'll go with this one, seems to be faster.

Comment: +1 for [localeCompare](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.9). :-)

Comment: May I suggest using `add` instead of `insertBefore`? Same syntax, just feels cleaner.

Comment: @Prinzhorn: I think there are some older IE quirks, but otherwise I'd agree that it would be cleaner.

Comment: @prinzhorn—`insertBefore` has been in the DOM Core since the begining. It's a general method and very well supported, whereas `add` is part of DOM HTML and specific to option and optgroup elements. Perhaps it's personal preference, but core methods seem more suitable where available and equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');

var sorted = Array.prototype.slice.call(select.options).sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.label < b.label) return -1;
    if(a.label > b.label) return 1;
    return 0;
});

for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    select.add(sorted[i]);
}
```

Sorted by [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option#Attributes). Just change it for other properties.

Note that `options` is **read only**.

https://tinker.io/9720d

Note: does not work IE 8 and below

Comment: Try that in IE8. You can't be sure that host objects can be passed to native methods like that without error. There is no specification that says you can, and ECMA-262 says host objects don't have to behave like native objects, so there is a specific warning that they may not (and in IE 8 and lower you can't).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods, one is to create an array of the option values (or text, whatever you want to sort on) and create an object with properties whose names are the option values (or text) and values are references to the options.

Sort the array, then iterate over it, using the member values to get the options from the object, e.g.

```
function sortOptionsByValue(select) {
  var a = [], o = {}, opt;
  for (var i=0, iLen=select.options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = select.options[i];
    a.push(opt.value);
    o[opt.value] = opt;
  }
  a.sort();
  while (i--) {
    select.insertBefore(o[a[i]], select.firstChild);
  }
  // Optional, make first option selected
  select.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

There are other methods, the above is just one. But it will work in any ECMA-262 compliant browser and doesn't depend on host objects acting like native objects, only that they behave like the W3C DOM Core says they should.