# Sorting multiple select dropdown options using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am using the following code for adding country where user selects country from one mutiple-select and adds to another multiple-select and on submit the countries of second multiple-select is inserted into database.

.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').click(function(){
        $('#country_list option:selected').appendTo('#country_select');
    });
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $('#country_select option:selected').appendTo('#country_list');
    });
    $('.add-all').click(function(){
        $('#country_list option').appendTo('#country_select');
    });
    $('.remove-all').click(function(){
        $('#country_select option').appendTo('#country_list');
    });
    $("#register").click(function() {  
    $("#country_select option").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
});
```

.html

```
  <select id="country_list" size="10" multiple style="min-width: 200px;">
   <option value="US">United States</option>
   <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
   <option value="IN">India</option>          
  </select>
  <table border="0">
  <tr><td><input type="button" class='add' value=">"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="button" class='remove' value="<"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="button" class='add-all' value=">>>"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="button" class='remove-all' value="<<<"/></td></tr>
  </table>
  <select size="10" name="country_select[]" id="country_select" multiple  style="min-width: 200px;">
  </select>
```

Here when add button is clicked the selected items in dropdown country-list is moved to country-select.

What I require is that when a country is added then it should be moved into the dropdown country-select in order of name. Currently when a country is added it goes to the bottom of the list in country-options.

I tried this [Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element) but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the following function each time an option moves to rearrange the select options from `#country_select` alphabetically

Js:

```
function reArrangeSelect() {
    $("#country_select").html($("#country_select option").sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }))
}
```

[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pJhLD/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/pJhLD/) | [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466196/1756941)

Answer (score 1):

Custom element sorter based on values

```
function optionSort(a, b) {
    return $(a).val() > $(b).val();
}

var opts = $('#selectID option').get();

$('#selectID ').html(opts.sort(optionSort))
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/5WgYK/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort the multiselect by selected whilst keeping the selected items at the top of the list, this will be useful.

```
$('#identifier option:selected').prependTo('#identifier');
$("#identifier").multiselect("refresh");
```