# JavaScript: Ignoring case while sorting options in a multiselect

Tags: javascript, sorting, multi-select, case-insensitive

I am trying to sort options in a `multiselect` while ignoring the case. I have seen methods for doing each of these things separately, but I'm not sure how to do them together.

Here is my HTML for sorting:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<label for="elliot">select:</label>
<select name="elliot" multiple="multiple" id="elliot1" style="height:140px;display:block;width: 200px;">
<option>d</option>
<option>Z</option>
<option>avery</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>Alive</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>b</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:sortSelect(elliot1);">Sort</button>
</form>
```

and here is my JavaScript (note: I am not looking for a jQuery solution):

```
function sortSelect(selElem) {
    var tmpAry = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
        tmpAry[i] = new Array();
        //tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
        tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
        tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
    }
    tmpAry.sort();
    while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
        selElem.options[0] = null;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
        var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
        selElem.options[i] = op;
    }
    return;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3ph/2/)

Comment: Ok, so what are you seeing?  What's not working?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/278509/1762224)...

Comment: What I have up here is working, but it is also sorting by case. I tried adding some code to ignore the case on the sort() but I was getting a "toLowerCase is not a function" errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the default sorting function like this:

```
tmpAry.sort(
  function (a, b) {
    var _a = a[0].toLowerCase();
    var _b = b[0].toLowerCase();
    if (_a < _b) return -1;
    if (_a > _b) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh3ph/7/)

Here is the ECMAScript [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) general form:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! The way I was trying it didn't have [0] so I guess it was not working with the array?

Comment: Yeah, you need to get the text from the select option.