# jQuery sorting <select> items by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$('select[name=items]').each( function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).find('option').sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }) );
});

<select name="items">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option value="1">XXX</option>
<option value="2">BBB</option>
<option value="3">RRR</option>
<option value="4">AAA</option>
```

How can I do sort without change position with 0 value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** for avoiding first element

```js
$('select[name=items]').each(function() {
  $(this).find('option:gt(0)').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="items">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">XXX</option>
  <option value="2">BBB</option>
  <option value="3">RRR</option>
  <option value="4">AAA</option>
</select>
```

or with help of **[attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

```js
$('select[name=items]').each(function() {
  $(this).find('option:not([value=0])').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="items">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">XXX</option>
  <option value="2">BBB</option>
  <option value="3">RRR</option>
  <option value="4">AAA</option>
</select>
```

**Note :** Also it's better to use **[`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append)** or **[`appentTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo)** instead of **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html)**