# Flask-Babel convert Flask-WTF SelectField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-babel

I want to convert **Flask-WTF** SelectField value with **Flask-Babel**.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
from flask_babel import _, lazy_gettext as _l

class PaymentStatus(enum.Enum):
    REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
    COMPLETED = 'COMPLETED'
    EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

payment_status = [(str(y), y) for y in (PaymentStatus)]

def course_list():
    return Course.query.all()

class PaymentForm(FlaskForm):
    course_name = QuerySelectField(_l('Course name'), validators=[required()], query_factory=course_list)
    status_of_payment = SelectField(_l('Payment Status'), choices=payment_status)
    # ...
    # ...
```

There, I want to localization the SelectField `choices` value and QuerySelectField `query_factory` value with **Flask-Babel**.

Is it possible..?, if so, any example or refer tutorial would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SelectField `choices` could be handled by `lazy_gettext()`.

[Quote from The Flask Mega-Tutorial Part XIII: I18n and L10n](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-i18n-and-l10n)

> Some string literals are assigned *outside of a request*, usually when the application is starting up, so at the time these texts are evaluated there is no way to know what language to use.
>
> Flask-Babel provides a lazy evaluation version of `_()` that is called `lazy_gettext()`.
>
> ```
> from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _l
>
> class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
>     username = StringField(_l('Username'), validators=[DataRequired()])
>     # ...
> ```

For `choices`

```py
from flask_babel import _, lazy_gettext as _l

class PaymentStatus(enum.Enum):
    REJECTED = _l('REJECTED')
    COMPLETED = _l('COMPLETED')
    EXPIRED = _l('EXPIRED')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

---

QuerySelectField `query_factory` accepts values *queried from the database*. These values should not be handled by Flask-Babel/babel. Cause the database stores data outside the Python source code.

Possible solutions:

- Add a translation field in the database table and update the translation manually. Or
- [Using a Third-Party Translation Service](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiv-ajax) on the webpage and handle it by AJAX

BTW, *The Flask Mega-Tutorial* made by Miguel Grinberg is a very famous Flask tutorial. All these situations are included in it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer @Simba :)

Comment: Yea, I learn a lot from Flask Mega Tutorial, that's very great tutorial from Miguel Grinberg :)

Comment: Imagine a language selector ```SelectField``` translated with Flask-Babel 
(e.g.: in English it would be something like: English, Spanish; but then in Spanish: español, inglés). What would it be the best way to sort the ```choices``` from the ```SelectField```? Go with JS like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/278509/488019 ?

Comment: I solved with this on `@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])` : `form.language.choices = sorted(constants.IETF_LANGUAGE_TAGS, key=lambda tuple: tuple[1])`