# Why does jQuery sort() select the wrong option when you append a new option via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for clarification on why this issue is happening, and what should be done to avoid this behaviour.

I have a `select` that will add new options on an event trigger. When this trigger fires I want to create a new `option` append to the `select` and then sort all the options in to an order (alphabetical or otherwise, does not matter for this issue). When I do this using the code below, the `option` is added to the `select` however the new option becomes selected even though a different `option` is the "selected" `option`.

[demo](https://codepen.io/brianbest/pen/NWWoLgq)

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $('select');
  select.append("<option value='9'>Nine</option>"); // This will become selected
  select.html(select.find('option').sort(function(x, y) {
    return $(x).text() > $(y).text() ? 1 : -1;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option>Choose a number</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="2" >Two</option>
    <option value="8" selected="true">Eight</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Edit**: The issue here is not that the options will be organized in one manner or another. The issue is that *after* the options are sorted the select displays the wrong option as the selected option. After the JS runs I would expect that Eight is still the selected option.

Comment: `n` comes after `Z` in Unicode. Try to sort with `.text().toLowerCase()` instead or use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Note that jQuery objects (the result of `find`), while array-like (they have numeric indices and a `length` property), should not be treated as arrays in all instances, especially when dealing with methods like `sort`, which mutate the original arrays.

Comment: It actually picks the last option in the resulting menu that is also below the `selected` option of the original menu. It appears to treat all options below the first `[selected]` one as `[selected]` and while appending just sets and resets the selected option, option by option. Hooray, jQuery is broken!

Comment: The correct duplicate for this question is [Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278089/215552) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200431/215552) for code that preserves your code and resets the selected option).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element)

Comment: Hey all, yes these solve my question. Thank you @SebastianSimon and Hereitic Monkey for the explanations as well as Goran Stoyanov for pointing to a way to avoid it. To be clear [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element/9200431#9200431) we've implemented