tom-select.js: reorder <options> (from html) after initialized?
I'm putting TomSelect on a <select><option>… element (ie. the options come from the plain html, not a js object). Then some time after it's rendered I would like to reorder the options. I have two possible solutions, but they both seem kind of hacky:

tomselect.destroy(), reorder the html elements, reinitialise tomselect
loop through tomselect.options and set the $order attribute to a new number and finally call tomselect.sync()

I feel like I should be able to just use the sortField option instead of sorting the options myself, but all the examples I've seen assume you're getting options from a js object. Is there a way for the sortField function to access the original html elements, so I could just change a dataset property / data attribute on them and use that as the sort field?

What if you sort the select options directly? Will Tom-Select resync it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466196/10512014

Did you tried something like onOptionAdd: function () { this.setTextboxValue(''); this.refreshOptions();}

My  "alternative 1" was sorting the select options directly – but as mentioned, tomselect doesn't notice it unless I destroy first and then reinitialise. I'm currently leaning towards "alternative 2", not sure how that onOptionAdd would make my code clearer since I'm not adding options, I just want them sorted based on an html attribute
